# Feedback effect of interactions : No interactions between quasiparticles if no external field?

Tags: condensed-matter, fermi-liquids

I am working with Coleman "Introduction to many body physics".

In the chapter 7 (pages 131-132) we deal with Fermi liquid and they talk about the Feedback effect of interactions of the quasi particles.

Let me introduces the notation.

$\epsilon_p^0$ : energy of a single quasiparticle interaction

$\epsilon_{p,\sigma}=\epsilon_p^0+\sum f_{p p' \sigma \sigma'} \delta n'_{p'\sigma'}$ : total energy of a quasiparticle including the interactions with the others (thus if only 1 q.p is present we find $\epsilon_p^0$).

$f_{p p' \sigma \sigma'}$ : Landau parameter representing the interactions between quasi particles $(p,\sigma)$ and $(p',\sigma')$

---

What he does is the following :

He considers an external field excitation (for example he enables a magnetic field). Thus, we will have :

$\epsilon_p^0 \rightarrow \epsilon_p^0 + \delta \epsilon_{p,\sigma}^0$

And using the expression of $\epsilon_{p,\sigma}$ he computes the response of the system.

$\epsilon_{p,\sigma} \rightarrow \epsilon_p^0 + \delta \epsilon_{p,\sigma}=\epsilon_p^0+\delta \epsilon_{p,\sigma}^0+\sum f_{p p' \sigma \sigma'} \delta n'_{p'\sigma'}$

And finally he finds that $\delta \epsilon_{p,\sigma} \propto \delta \epsilon_{p,\sigma}^0$

But I don't understand this result. Indeed, if we imagine no external field, thus $\delta \epsilon_{p,\sigma}^0$, it would mean that $\sum f_{p p' \sigma \sigma'} \delta n'_{p'\sigma'}=0$. And thus no interactions between quasi particles...?

How the interactions between quasiparticles could be $0$ without an external field ?